# Followup intent with multiple parameters

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent on Dialogflow where the user can ask something similar to this:

"What is the best price for shoes last month?"

Where translate to the parameters:

"What is the @case @metric for @item @date-period?"

So far so good. This intent outputs a context and works fine.

Now,

How do I create a follow-up context that allows the user to update one or more parameters keeping the remaining intact?

Eg:

"And what is the worse?" (only the case is updated)
"And what is the best for sandals?" (case and item are updated)
"And what is the worse last week?" (case and date-period are updated)
"And how about boots last week?" (item and date-period updated, )
etc.

I mean, I have four parameters, and I would like to provide to the user the ability to continue the conversation (context) changing one or more parameters.

There is any way to create some kind of "smart follow-up intent" or do I need to create all possible combinations follow-up intents?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding an output context for your original intent, lets say "search". Make this intent calls your fulfillment and save the parameters, something like this:

```
app.data.case = app.getArgument('case');
app.data.metric = app.getArgument('metric');
app.data.item = app.getArgument('item');
app.data.date-period = app.getArgument('date-period');
```

Now create another intent and add some [user says expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mSWg.png) that covers all parameters and have as [input context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWLHU.png) the same context you put on the original intent. Make this intent also calls your fulfillment and from what parameters are filled you can realize what the user is trying to change so whatever the user has not provided you can get it back from what you had saved before:

```
let _case = app.data.case;
```